# npm build gives "Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

I have a reactjs/typescript project, running on windows 10. Im trying to build by ts-scripts with

> "rimraf ../wwwroot/* && react-scripts-ts build && copyfiles
>   ./build/**/* ../wwwroot/ -u 1

This has worked ok before, but when I removed the node_modules-folder, re-run the npm install-command and then the command above I get the error message

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation
>   failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

I have no idea why. After googling Ive seen

> NODE_OPTIONS="–max-old-space-size=2048"
>   but I dont know where to put this

**Full error message**

Last few GCs

```
[11376:0000024682F49880]    60039 ms: Mark-sweep 2034.1 (2085.2) -> 2033.7 (2085.2) MB, 1029.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.073, current mu = 0.006) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[11376:0000024682F49880]    61094 ms: Mark-sweep 2034.4 (2085.2) -> 2034.1 (2085.7) MB, 1047.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.039, current mu = 0.007) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


 JS stacktrace 
==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 000001CDF84DC5C1]
Security context: 0x007044b9e6e1 <JSObject>
    1: bindChildrenWorker(aka bindChildrenWorker) [000001AD1C0ACD59] [C:\Users\robcar\source\repos\Boost\Boost.Web\ClientApp\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:~27657] [pc=000001CDF8FA47CA](this=0x03da79d826f1 <undefined>,node=0x034b8724ab71 <NodeObject map = 000000660468F931>)
    2: bind(aka bind) [000001AD1C0AE2D9] [C:\Users\robcar\source\repos\B...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6B5EA121A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4810
 2: 00007FF6B5E7A5B6 node::MakeCallback+4518
 3: 00007FF6B5E7AFA0 node_module_register+2160
 4: 00007FF6B610B3EE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF6B610B31F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF6B6649304 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+11476
 7: 00007FF6B663FA67 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+25543
 8: 00007FF6B663DFDC v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+18748
 9: 00007FF6B6646F57 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2343
10: 00007FF6B6646FD6 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2470
11: 00007FF6B61E9DD7 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55
12: 00007FF6B6281ABA v8::internal::WasmJs::Install+29530
13: 000001CDF84DC5C1
```

Answer (score 36):

I had a similar issue, although on a Mac computer.
Setting an environment variable did the trick for me. That way, your node process will take the value and use it independently of which script you're running.

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```

The run your command again. Good Luck!

Comment: Hi eespejel. Thanks for your reply and guiding me to environment variables. Ive tested this on windows (through the menus) but it did not work :/. If any other windows-user got this to work, please comment below.

Comment: In my case the code I was writing had a memory leak, fixing the code fixed the issue.

Answer (score 18):

The solution which I used was to upgrade the node js version from **v10** to **v12**.

---

The command `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096` works but has limitations, e.g. you should have ample memory on your machine to run the production build.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue on Windows. The solution was to set the NODE_OPTIONS variable before running npm run build. To set this variable, simply run `set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192`

Comment: This helped to resolve the issue. The othe options won't work if the issue is within any dependency libraries.

Answer (score 9):

I got a fix after increasing the node max_old_space. Here is the fix.

Instead of running npm start or ng start. Run the below command

```js
node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

OR

You can add the command in `package.json` file as well

```json
"start": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve"
```

Answer (score 5):

The root cause of the problem is the large source file sizes.

You can resolve the issue in 2 steps.

1. First try to increase space size and check the application. If the problem is cause by your source code, then this can be resolved by increasing the Node Heap Size as below,

```json
"start": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 start",
"build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build"
```

2. Second step is setting the **Environment Variable**.
   If the problem lies within your dependencies, you may need to increase the Node Heap allocation globally to resolve the issue.
   For Windows: `set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`
   For Linux:   `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`

Also note that, if you are using very low memory like 512MB, then you will have to upgrade it to at least 2GB to get the better result.

Here I used 4096MB = 4GB size, but you can change this according to your machine configuration specifically RAM. You can set it to 2GB or 1GB and check the application.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the solution is to increase memory limit. This way the issue is always postponed.

I've encounter this issue 2 times. I've solved, for each time:

1. using a specific version of `node` (`v12.11.1`, `react v16.13.1` and `react-scripts v3.2.0`);
2. switching from `npm` to `yarn` (`node v12.11.1`, `react v16.13.1` and `react-scripts v3.4.1`).

In addition, check your `package.json`, delete `package-lock.json`, remove `node-modules` folder and try to install your dependencies again.

Next try to build your project.

Comment: This didn't work in my case. When we execute `npm install`, it shows vulnerabilities and don't allow us to use older version for `react-script`. I used the `--max-old-space` and also increased my VM memory to `2GB`

Comment: I agree with this answer. Increasing the memory limit just postpones the crash.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wrote in my package.json run command

> "scripts": {
> "build": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 build/build.js"
> }

basically, you have to run --max_old_space_size=4096 before your actual build command

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this issue in my `Nuxt.js` environment as well.

As everyone says here, appllying the `--max_old_space_size={size}` with robust amount provided seemed to work for me. However, since I made some additional remediation on my `Nuxt.js` app stack, the same symptom has reappeared...

Furthermore, I also tried the `Node.js` option `--heapsnapshot-near-heap-limit={number}` and it SEEMED to work, not persistently.

Anyway, along with searching for another fix via [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html) or somewhere else, I intened to do the cord review so that I can expect if there is something redundant within our application stack.

Answer (score -4):

I have been facing this problem for some time. The problem is most likely caused by a dependancy or component which is a large .js file. I am currently using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit) to successfully fix the issue.

You basically install it globally:

```
npm install -g increase-memory-limit
```

And then from within your project root you run:

```
increase-memory-limit
```

Which will append `--max-old-space-size=4096` in all node calls inside your `node_modules/.bin/*` files.

Comment: Rather than fixing the issue, this had broken my runtime. Had to delete and npm install to fix the issue.

Comment: This is a very dangerous solution. Set NODE_OPTIONS to pass the parameter

Comment: yeap, for me as well. Broken everything